# regex match css class name from single string containing multiple classes

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I have a long string that contains multiple css classes. With regex I would like to match every class name as I then need to replace these class names like so:

```
<span>CLASSNAME</span>
```

I have tried for hours to come up with a solution and I think I am close however for certain class names I am not able to exclude closing curly brackets from the match.

Here is a sample string I have been carrying out testing on:

```
#main .items-Outer p{ font-family:Verdana; color: #000000; font-size: 50px; font-weight: bold; }#footer .footer-inner p.intro{ font-family:Arial; color: #444444; font-size: 30; font-weight: normal; }.genericTxt{ font-family:Courier; color: #444444; font-size: 30; font-weight: normal; }
```

And here is the the regex I came up with so far:

```
((^(?:.+?)(?:[^{]*))|((?:\})(?:.+?)(?:[^{]*)))
```

Please look at the screenshot I am attaching as it will show more clearly the matches I get. My problem is that I would obviously like to exclude curly brackets from any match.

[image: regex matches]

To clarify, example of matches I am after are:

- ## main .items-Outer p
- ## footer .footer-inner p.intro
- .genericTxt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If and only if* there won't be any nested curly braces, the following should work:

```
/\.(-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(?![^\{]*\})/
```

Here's [a demo](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5C.(-%3F%5B_a-zA-Z%5D%2B%5B_a-zA-Z0-9-%5D*)(%3F!%5B%5E%5C%7B%5D*%5C%7D)&input=%23main%20.items-Outer%20p%7B%20font-family%3AVerdana%3B%20color%3A%20%23000000%3B%20font-size%3A%2050px%3B%20font-weight%3A%20bold%3B%20%7D%23footer%20.footer-inner%20p.intro%7B%20font-family%3AArial%3B%20color%3A%20%23444444%3B%20font-size%3A%2030%3B%20font-weight%3A%20normal%3B%20%7D.genericTxt%7B%20font-family%3ACourier%3B%20color%3A%20%23444444%3B%20font-size%3A%2030%3B%20font-weight%3A%20normal%3B%20%7D)!

Note that I'm referencing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names) for the valid-CSS-class-name regex.

**EDIT**

I just read your comment clarifying that you wish to match the entire *selector*, not just *class names*. In that case, try this, although I'm not as confident about its robustness:

```
/[^}]*(?=\{|$)/
```

Here's [a demo of that one](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5B%5E%7D%5D*(%3F%3D%5C%7B%7C%24)&input=%23main%20.items-Outer%20p%7B%20font-family%3AVerdana%3B%20color%3A%20%23000000%3B%20font-size%3A%2050px%3B%20font-weight%3A%20bold%3B%20%7D%23footer%20.footer-inner%20p.intro%7B%20font-family%3AArial%3B%20color%3A%20%23444444%3B%20font-size%3A%2030%3B%20font-weight%3A%20normal%3B%20%7D.genericTxt%7B%20font-family%3ACourier%3B%20color%3A%20%23444444%3B%20font-size%3A%2030%3B%20font-weight%3A%20normal%3B%20%7D).

Comment: Updated this solution in response to comment to Anirudha's solution.

Comment: Yes works great. I was getting cross eyed trying to find a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the regex for that

```
(?:(\}|^)).*?(?:\{)
```

Comment: thanks for your help, and sorry I might have not explained well what I need. I need the whole class name. For instance taking the string I posted aove, I would need these matches : #main .items-Outer p and #footer .footer-inner p.intro and .genericTxt

Comment: thank you for that but I am still getting curly braces in the matches. Am i doing something wrong with your answer? I have tested it here http://regexpal.com/

Comment: @effectica it would not be included in the result..access it with value property of regex

Answer (score 0):

Assuming str contains your CSS, the following regex:

```
str.match(/(?:#\w+\s+)?\.[\w-]+(?:\s+\w+\s*\.\w+|\s+\w+)?/ig)
```

returns:

```
["#main .items-Outer p", "#footer .footer-inner p.intro", ".genericTxt"]
```

The regex is:

```
(?:#\w+\s+)?      -- optional leading CSS id, i.e. #abc
\.[\w-]+          -- CSS classname, i.e. .ab-c
(?:
    \s+\w+\s*\.\w+  -- optional CSS elt followed by classname, i.e. p.abc
|                   -- or
    \s+\w+          -- optional CSS elt, i.e. p
)?
```

See [demo](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28%3F%3A%23%5Cw%2B%5Cs%2B%29%3F%5C.%5B%5Cw-%5D%2B%28%3F%3A%5Cs%2B%5Cw%2B%5Cs%2a%5C.%5Cw%2B%7C%5Cs%2B%5Cw%2B%29%3F&input=%23main%20.items-Outer%20p%7B%20font-family%3AVerdana%3B%20color%3A%20%23000000%3B%20font-size%3A%2050px%3B%20font-weight%3A%20bold%3B%20%7D%23footer%20.footer-inner%20p.intro%7B%20font-family%3AArial%3B%20color%3A%20%23444444%3B%20font-size%3A%2030%3B%20font-weight%3A%20normal%3B%20%7D.genericTxt%7B%20font-family%3ACourier%3B%20color%3A%20%23444444%3B%20font-size%3A%2030%3B%20font-weight%3A%20normal%3B%20%7D)

Comment: I would like to point out that my solution works irrespective of the presence, absence or nesting of curly-braces.

Comment: bug, this will also match things that are not class names, within curly brackets e.g. line-height: 1.18; within curly brackets results in .18 matching.